# Jquery get outer html and hide element with class

Tags: jquery, hide

I have the following markup

```
<div>
   <div class="myclass">
      <p>some text <span class="my-other-class">abc</span></p>
      <p>some text <span class="my-other-class">abc</span></p>
      <p>some text <span class="my-other-class">abc</span></p>
      ...
   </div>
</div>
```

I use the following to get the outer html of an element:

```
var html = $('.myclass').prop('outerHTML');
```

The returned html has some elements with class `.my-other-class` which i want to hide. Whats the syntax to hide those elements on the html returned but not on the original? So something along the lines of:

```
$html.('.my-other-class').hide()
```

Comment: `$html.('.my-other-class').hide() ` should be something like `$(html).find('.my-other-class').hide() `

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen that doesn't update the html variable when i do: `$(html).find('.my-other-class').hide(); console.log(html);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clone element `.myclass` then hide `.my-other-class` in the cloned element:

```js
var clone = $('.myclass').clone();

// use .remove() if you want to remove it from the html returned
clone.find('.my-other-class').hide(); 

console.log(clone[0].outerHTML) // or clone.prop('outerHTML')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <div class="myclass">
      <p>some text <span class="my-other-class">abc</span></p>
      <p>some text <span class="my-other-class">abc</span></p>
      <p>some text <span class="my-other-class">abc</span></p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `clone.outerHTML()` is not a functon